# Archive all Outlook sub-folders into another sub-folder

Tags: vba, outlook

Afternoon All,

I have the following structure in my Outlook:

```
Mapi > peter*********com > !!!INCIDENTS > !APS PV >!Archive
```

[image]

I would like to place ALL subfolders in subfolder `!APS PV` into subfolder `!Archive` .

My code looks to loop through the subfolder and moves each. I have no issues moving the subfolders, it's loading all the subfolders into an array. No items are being returned.

```
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items

    On Error GoTo MsgErr
'    Set Inbox Reference
    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent
    Set Items = olFolder.Items
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("!!!INCIDENTS")
    Set Items = olFolder.Items
    Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("!APS PV")
    Set Items = olFolder.Items

'   // Loop through the Items in the folder backwards
    For lngCount = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items(lngCount)

        Debug.Print Item.Subject

        If Item.Class = olMail Then
'           // Set SubFolder of Inbox
            Set SubFolder = olFolder.Folders("!Archive")
'           // Mark As Read
            Item.UnRead = False
'           // Move Mail Item to sub Folder
            Item.Move SubFolder
        End If
    Next lngCount
```

The `Items.Count` returns zero despite many subfolders existing.

Peter

Comment: Seems like folders are not items and you have to loop through folders collection in the folder. See [Using visual basic to access subfolder in Inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8322523/9439330)

Comment: Strange as olFolder.Items.Item does exist in the object hierarchy. I'm seeing an ewrror being raised at olFolder.Folders("!!!INCIDENTS") The attempted operation failed.  An object could not be found"

Comment: Item and Items are Outlook data types.  Trying to use them as private variables gets Outlook confused.  Try `MyItem` and `MyItems` or `ItemCrnt` and `ItemsCrnt`.

Comment: Is `Debug.Print olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent` what you think it is?

Comment: Looks all in order: Mapi
p********.com
!!!INCIDENTS
!APS PV
Just not items being returned from Items.Count

Comment: You cannot get to the line with Items.Count if `olFolder.Folders("!!!INCIDENTS")` generates "The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found".

Comment: What do you see with `Debug.Print olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent`? Use@niton so I note your response.

Comment: Compile Error: Expected expressioin in the debug window

Comment: Not in the immediate pane. Place the line in the code just before `Set olFolder = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent`.

Comment: Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Debug.Print olNs
    Debug.Print olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent shows

Comment: Mapi
p***.****@****.com This look reasonable

Answer (score 0):

You can list all the folders to see which ones are available.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FoldersList()

    Dim olNs As NameSpace

    Dim olMailbox As Folder

    Set olNs = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Debug.Print olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent
    Set olMailbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent

    processFolder olMailbox

End Sub

Private Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Folder)

    Dim oFolder As Folder

    Debug.Print oParent

    If oParent = "!!!INCIDENTS" Then MsgBox "found"

    If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
        For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
            processFolder oFolder
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```