# How to grab an email from specific Outlook folder with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to grab target email received today from specific folder. My current VBA code is :

```
Sub ExportOutlookTableToExcel()

Dim oLookInspector As Inspector
Dim oLookMailitem As MailItem

Dim oLookWordDoc As Word.Document
Dim oLookWordTbl As Word.Table

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook 
Dim xlWrkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim Today As String
Today = Date


'Grab Email Item
 Set oLookMailitem =Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items("Apples Sales")

 Set oLookInspector = oLookMailitem.GetInspector

 Set oLookWordDoc = oLookInspector.WordEditor
```

However, my email is in specific folder called "Apples", if i move it to Inbox folder it works with CurrentFolder emthod. Is it any way to specify in which folder VBA should grab an email?

Comment: Is the folder you need a subfolder of `Inbox`?

Comment: yes it is a subfolder

Comment: Please, try `Set oLookMailitem = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Apples").items("Apples Sales")`. Of course, supposing that the subject of the incriminated mail is "Apples Sales" and it exists in subfolder "Apples".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using visual basic to access subfolder in Inbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322432/using-visual-basic-to-access-subfolder-in-inbox)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the folder is the subfolder on the Inbox folder, try

```
set folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Folder Name")
```

if it is on the same level as the Inbox, use

```
set folder = Application.Session.GetDEfaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("Folder Name")
```

Comment: it shows : An object could not be found

Comment: Well, did you provide the right folder name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NameSpace.PickFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.pickfolder) method which displays the `Pick Folder` dialog box. The `Pick Folder` dialog box is a modal dialog box which means that code execution will not continue until the user either selects a folder or cancels the dialog box. The method returns a `Folder` object that represents the folder that the user selects in the dialog box, or `Nothing` if the dialog box is canceled by the user.

So, each time your VBA macro runs you can choose the right folder at runtime. Otherwise, you will have to specify the hard-coded folder name.

The [NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder) method returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default ``Inbox`or`Calendar` folder for the user who is currently logged on.

Then you can use the [Folder.Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.folders) property which returns the `Folders` collection that represents all the folders contained in the specified `Folder`. So, you may find a subfolder.

```
Set item = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI)".GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Apples").Items("Apples Sales")
```