How to hardcode an Outlook folder
This code was given in a previous thread. I need to know how to hard code the name of a folder.
This code brings up a navigator to choose the folder. Instead, I want to delete the 6 month old contents of the subfolder in my Inbox named "JOHN SMITH".
Sub DeleteOlderThan6months()

    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim Date6months As Date
    Dim ItemsOverMonths As Outlook.Items

    Dim DateToCheck As String

    Date6months = DateAdd("d", -182, Now())
    Date6months = Format(Date6months, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    Set oFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder 'or set your folder
                  'THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SET THE FOLDER AS "JOHN SMITH"

    DateToCheck = "[Received] <= """ & Date6months & """"

    Set ItemsOverMonths = oFolder.Items.Restrict(DateToCheck)

    For i = ItemsOverMonths.Count To 1 Step -1
    ItemsOverMonths.Item(i).Delete
    Next

    Set ItemsOverMonths = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing

End Sub


https://stackoverflow.com/a/8322523/478884 shows how to access a subfolder in your Inbox.
